Remapping PD1 to be a GPIO STM32Duino
I would like to remap the PD1 PD1-OSC_OUT pin on the STM32F103C8 running arduino framework.
Originally on bluepill these pins are used up to drive a Xtal however the board im working on uses the internal Xtal and PD1 is used to drive a on-board led in such way that if it is pulled low it will complete the circuit for a led that is already connected to 3.3v.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community I want to remap PD1 'PD1-OSC_OUT' to be a GPIO on arduino framework. i have no idea how its hard to tell what im asking..

From Arduino IDE Tools menu, choose "Generic STM32F1 Series" as the Board, then choose "Generic F103C8Tx" as Board Part Number. This configuration uses internal HSI clock, and PD_1 is configured as Digital Pin D36.
